# precomputed kernels with spark MLlib

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, svm, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm doing to do some machine learning in spark using MLlib. so basically, I'm trying to fit my model using a precomputed kernel with a kernel method as SVM.

my question is : doest spark support that kind of data (the precomputed kernels)? if it's yes, would you please refer to an example, otherwise what are the alternatives ?

Thank you ;)